# image inside view shows bottom white space

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, slideshow

I have a slideshow images in my view controller I changed the content mode to scale to fill, but it show white space from the bottom

[image]

[image]

[image]

my slideshow func

```
func imageSlideShowInitialize(source: [SDWebImageSource]) {
    slideshow.slideshowInterval = 5.0
    slideshow.pageIndicatorPosition = .init(horizontal: .center, vertical: .under)
    slideshow.contentScaleMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill


    slideshow.activityIndicator = DefaultActivityIndicator()
    slideshow.delegate = self

    slideshow.setImageInputs(source)

    let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didTap))
    slideshow.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}
```

Comment: Use `.scaleAspectFill`

Comment: @Aznix same brother, it shows a white space below the image !

Comment: @Jacob - tough to tell... your picture shows a "rounded corner outline" but we don't see any code that is creating that... you also show `slideshow.pageIndicatorPosition = .init(horizontal: .center, vertical: .under)` ... is the "white space" actually the white dots of the pageIndicator on white background below the image?

Comment: @DonMag you saved my day... thanks I did not notice that. it fixes the white space when I removed it